# Open multiple tabs in a browser using Playwright

Tags: python, python-3.x, playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to open multiple tabs from the same browser using the mentioned playwright code. The browser I'm trying to use is Firefox. Firefox is opening multiple windows instead of tabs. With Chrome it is successfully opening multiple tabs from the same browser. I have searched for different solutions but the result was the same.

```py
import time
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def run(playwright):
    firefox = playwright.firefox
    browser = firefox.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://google.com")
    new_tab = context.new_page()
    new_tab.goto("https://playwright.dev")
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.close()

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

Comment: That's not supported yet. There is [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/3696) that you can go an upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    with context.expect_page() as new:
        page.evaluate("window.open('https://www.google.com')")
        page2 = new.value

    page.bring_to_front()
    sleep(2)
    print(context.pages)
    page2.bring_to_front()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?